# Labels location on print view way off IN QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm having a weird issue with labels. I have two point layer files showing cities. They are both labelled using the same parameters (Around Point, 2mm from centre, etc.).

They both show up fine in the main working window (see screenshot).

However, once I get to print/page view, one of the layers places the labels really far away from their corresponding points. I can't figure out a reason why this would be the case. Any thoughts?[image]